# Text inserted in a Word form field is automatically formatted

Tags: date, ms-word, formatting, formfield

We have a program that makes MS Word (2010) automation, and loads text into Word Form Fields.
It has run for years now, and suddenly on certain computers of a customer, a strange behavior happens.

We have 3 fields in our template that display dates. Those fields are configured as regular text (no formatting at all). We format the date as a string (DD.MM.YYYY, swiss style) before in our program and then load this string into the field. Nothing exceptional here...

And guess what? in two fields the date is automatically formatted as M/D/YYYY. In the third one it keeps the value with the right format.

This is a very rare case; several users can manipulate the document. We suppose one computer in the chain does this formatting but it's hard to identify.

Do you have any idea of what parameter could cause this automatic formatting?

Many thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel  > Region & Language > Formats determines whether Word 2010 interprets 11/12 as 11 Dec, or 12 Nov.  I guess it might also affect the formatting?